# Generic method and converting: how to define that Type 1 is convertible to Type 2

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I defined this method:

```
public static List<T2> ConvertList<T1, T2>(List<T1> param) where T1:class where T2:class
{
    List<T2> result = new List<T2>();

    foreach (T1 p in param)
        result.Add((T2)p);

    return result;
}
```

For converting Lists of Type 1 to Lists of Type 2.

Unfortunately I forgot, that C# compiler cannot say at this stage that `T1` is convertible to `T2`, so it throws error:

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type T1 to T2

Can someone direct me how to do it properly? I need this method for now only to convert list of custom class to list of `object`, so as in .NET everything derives from `object` it should work.

Basically what I would expect is some syntax to tell compiler that T2 (`object`) is base for T1 (`MyClass`), so something like:

```
public static List<T2> ConvertList<T1, T2>(List<T1> param) where T2: base of T1
```

(... **where T2: base of T1**)

Comment: Use `where T2 : T1`.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for showing direction, but I think you wanted to say `where T1 : T2`

Comment: Maybe. Your wording is a bit confusing as to which direction you wanted it to go.

Comment: You realise you could just do `list.Cast<T2>().ToList()` right?

Comment: @Jamiec no I didn't realise it, thanks for info - I will use this method instead of my foreach loop. Things like this show me how much more I have to learn :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could specify it in a generic parameter:

```
public static List<T2> ConvertList<T1, T2>(List<T1> param) 
                 where T1:class,T2 
                 where T2:class
{
    List<T2> result = new List<T2>();

    foreach (T1 p in param)
        result.Add((T2)p);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was looking for. Why I didn't think of this syntax?